# Changing the tabular data to another table using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I tried to implement to display data in a table with the button click. Now I am trying to move the data from the table to the below the continue table. In this code, when I enter the input value from the json object and click the submit button, data will display in a table with a continue button and a empty table below.When I click continue the data in the above table should move to table which is located below the continue button. Here is my code [Sample http://jsfiddle.net/e254w/6/] Can anyone please suggest the idea of implement the scenario?

Krish

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/e254w/6/

Answer (score 0):

One way to approach this would be to remove the row from the first table and append it to the second.

This line finds the second row in the first table, removes it if it exists and appends it to the second table.

```
$('#datatable').find('tr').eq(1).remove().appendTo($('#seconddatatable'));
```

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e254w/10/)

Updated fiddle - this works for me first entering `122233334444`, then entering `122223355552`

Comment: I am not seeing any thing when I click continue button

Comment: it is working only if i hit submit button again but not continue button ...I scenario that I am trying to implement is when I click the continue button..I should copy the data from the top table to the bottom table.