# move data from table1 to table 2 using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a question. I tried to implement to display data in a table with the button click. Now I am trying to move the data from the table to the below the continue table. In this code, when I enter the input value from the json object and click the submit button, data will display in a table with a continue button and a empty table below.When I click continue the data in the above table should move to table which is located below the continue button.

I got it worked but it is work only if you click submit button second time.. I am trying to implement the scenario but clicking continue button. Any suggestions? Here is my code  [link http://jsfiddle.net/e254w/11/]

Comment: Please post your code. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149890/prevent-posts-with-links-to-jsfiddle-and-no-code

Comment: Why post this again? [Changing the tabular data to another table using jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17821523/changing-the-tabular-data-to-another-table-using-jquery/17821777?noredirect=1#comment26011123_17821777)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the simplest one (IMO)

```
$('#continue').click(function(){
    $("#submitid").click();
});
```

Just submit once and then continue clicking on `Continue` button.

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/e254w/16/)

Comment: thanks a lot for the response and how to remove the data and hide the table1 once I moved the data.. I did .hide() but it is not working...

Comment: Welcome :-) `$('#datatable').remove();` will remove the table.

Comment: thanks a lot and I am trying to hide the continue button when I do $('#datatable #continue').remove(); but dint work..I have one question why some times I am getting the   alert("Row doesn't exist in json object: " + rowId); sometimes it happening going to the else block

Comment: 1. `$('#continue').remove()` would work. 2. If you put value in the text box that is not existed in the row/json (Currently you have only 122233334444).

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/e254w/27/ I have a another column in the second table. How to add that same column in the row...Can you please check that fiddle link??

Comment: this code has more than one item http://jsfiddle.net/e254w/30/ when I try to add the second item it is not going to table1 it is going to table2 and second item is adding to the table1 so I am able to see only one item...

Comment: I'm confused now, can you rephrase the problem.